# PHP 7 session not getting cleared via garbage collector in Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS

Tags: php, ubuntu, session, garbage-collection, inode

In `/etc/cron.d/php`, a cron runs that tries to execute `/usr/lib/php/sessionclean` file which is suppose to clear sesssion files present inside `/var/lib/php/sessions/` but its not clearing it.

Ideally php garbage collector runs via probablity as mentioned in `/etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini` but Debian sets `session.gc_probability = 0`
 and runs its own cron. For security reasons, Debian sets a tough permission on `/var/lib/php/sessions/` folder and php gc access or perform delete hence debian runs a cron `/etc/cron.d/php` as root.

But it seems, this script `/usr/lib/php/sessionclean` is not working, a lot of expired session files are still there in `/var/lib/php/sessions/` folder which keeps on growing and will eventually cause inode issue.

Any suggestion as why this is happening and how to fix it.

Comment: I finally moved on to use redis for session management and hence discarded the overall php session file usages and gc issues.